# How To Edit TwLauncher lnk path/application/label

Tags: launcher

How does one edit TwLauncher home-screen shortcuts (lnk) internal information (NOT JUST ICON) to change application/path/title-text?; Where is the homescreem layout/presentation/shortcut information hiding? Why isn't this information available from the HelpSystem? How can I edit my help system? What evil has hidden this information so effectively? How do I edit shortcuts on ADW .launcher? How do I go about finding/learning how to findout how to edit information on ANY given launcher?

Comment: You have 3 separate questions. You should post them separately.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the TW launcher stores the informations about the home screens icons and the packages icons in a SQL database file inside its data folder for which the full path can be, as for example for the stock TW launcher on a Galaxy Y phone (GingerBread v.2.3.6), /data/data/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/databases/launcher.db

To view the content you need a SQL viewer app, to edit the content you need a SQL database editor.

I don't think Evil has any part on hidden so well what you are looking for; I think is just a kind of obscurity by complexity ;)

And for the Help part of your question, I'm sorry but I don't have clues.

Anyway, hope that my answer will be of some help to you.

All the best.

Hal Ex